# .NET Core 3.1 Logging in a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I am trying to find some good examples/explanations of .NET Core 3.x logging using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging class.

A lot of the ones I've seen using this only apply to ASP.NET Core applications.

My goal is to log not only to console, but to a file too. I have used NLog in the past, but I don't want anything that revolves around that or other logging frameworks.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/fundamentals-of-logging-in-dotnet-core

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging* package is to provide a standard way for logging in an application and building the abstractions on external logging providers (serilog, nlog, etc). So you just have to configure *ILoggerFactory* and use the *ILogger* interface.

Good example with console app - [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#nhca).

If you don't want to use logging frameworks it will be tricky to implement your own logger provider to a file because of concurrency.

Also, see this article if you want to know more about logging and performance problems acquired with it - [High-performance logging in .NET Core](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/high-performance-logging-in-net-core).

Comment: Do I need to have NLog or Serilog as a logging provider?  If I simply want to add logging to a file, can I do that without NLog/Serilog/log4net ?

Comment: @MikeMilw2002 simply, yes, you need. It gives you the most powerful way for logging with several important features like output format, partitioning of log files, asynchronous writing, etc. All of this matters when you will try to analyze behaviour of your app. On another hand you can try to implement your own logging provider to a file and it will be a good way to learn new things. For example, provider may consist of concurrent queue with log messages and a loop for writing them to a file.